# How to dynamically change bin size in bar chart (dc.js)?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

So I am calling the below code multiple times but the issue is that the bar chart bin size is stuck to the first data that I am putting in rest everything is changing as it should but not the bin size.

```
barChart
        .width(1080)
        .height(138)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 50})
        .dimension(key_map[$(this).text()].Dim)
        .group(key_map[$(this).text()].Group)
        .colors(['#6baed6'])
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(key_map[$(this).text()].Dim)) 
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .elasticY(true)
        .yAxis().ticks(4);

    barChart.elasticX(true).filterAll();dc.redrawAll();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what bin size you are talking about. This looks like an ordinal bar chart (x scale and xUnits), in which case binning would be by ordinal/categorical values. If your data is linear you should be using `d3.scale.linear` etc, but I am not sure if that is your question either. Perhaps you could spell out the expected and actual behavior; that's often a good way to frame a question.

Comment: Yes, I have different categories, The issue is that when I first make the Chart it shows all the categories, But when I try adding different data to the chart dynamically it shows only x number of categories from the new data not all of them. for example, the first data had 6 categories and after changing the data source for the chart(dim and group) I get only 6 categories from the new data. rather than 10 of them @Gordon

Comment: I dunno, if you have elasticX enabled, the chart should display the new data. Guess I’d have to see a running example to see what you’re talking about. Here’s [an example where it works](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/transitions/ordinal-bar-transitions.html).

Comment: Thank you @Gordon. But that example is not what I am exactly looking for. I have uploaded a video describing by problem [Link To Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eKX7W7W1UkcXCCzhSn5g_yp6eK38xNRz) In the video you will see as I select different data source from a dropdown, the data changes but the number of bars on the bar chart remains the same as the initial data. [Link To video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eKX7W7W1UkcXCCzhSn5g_yp6eK38xNRz)

Comment: My point is that the example does work. The number of bars changes when the data changes. Not sure why your code always produces 10 bars but I don’t think it has to do with the code you’ve pasted. You’d have to include a complete example for anyone to troubleshoot this for you: the rest of the crossfilter initialization code for this chart, or preferably a running example. Otherwise we’re just guessing.

Comment: The only thing that I see is off about the snippet you posted is that you are initializing the x scale domain with the crossfilter dimension. This should be an array of keys. However, you call elasticX later which should tell the chart to read the keys from the group, so maybe this gets ignored.

Comment: Yes, you guessed it right @Gordon So, The array of keys was getting ignored even though I was calling elasticX(true); So I ended up calling chart.focus([all_the_keys_from_the group]); And it works perfectly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gordon, I finally figured it out.

The array of keys was getting ignored even though I was calling `elasticX(true);` So I ended up calling `chart.focus([all_the_keys_from_the group]);` And it works perfectly now.

```
barChart
    .dimension(key_map[$(this).text()].Dim)
    .group(key_map[$(this).text()].Group)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(key_map[$(this).text()].Dim)) 
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticX(true);
    var focus_keys = [];

    key_map[$(this).text()].Group.all().forEach(element => {
        focus_keys.push(element.key);
    });

    barChart.focus(focus_keys);
    barChart.filterAll(); dc.redrawAll();
```

Comment: I'm glad you got this working. However, this is not what I was talking about, so I want to leave a note for anyone who finds this later. It looks like you are initializing the x scale domain with the crossfilter dimension, but it takes an array: `.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(key_map[$(this).text()].Dim))`. If you set `.elasticX(true)` the domain should be calculated automatically. Calling `.focus()` is a more complicated way of setting the x scale domain (and not idiomatic).

Comment: @Gordon following your advice I tried adding `key_map[$(this).text()].Group.all().forEach(element => {
        focus_keys.push(element.key);
    });` `.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(focus_keys))` focus_keys(basically extracting keys from the group) to the domain and calling elasticX(true) but it still does not seem to work. Also keep in mind that I have a very old version v1.7.5

Comment: Oh wow that is ancient! I am not sure how this worked back then, but I was trying to say that setting the domain and elasticX are mutually exclusive. Anyway, if it works for you, that's great. I mostly wanted to leave a comment so that people who come across this don't consider it a best practice.